# Edge style autodetected phone number links

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

How can you stlye a autodetected phone number link in Edge. I looked into the markup and Edge doesn't add any `<a>` tags around it, like the iPhone which can be styled. They always have the standard Ede blue color and text-underline.

However I want it in an dark gray, and not underlined.

**How would a CSS selector look, to style the autodetected phone number links in edge?**

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/9m4cb6pq/

**What I tried**

Setting **`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`** However I don't want to use that, since not all users will be able to set a correct telphone number link an the featrue is quite usefull.

**EDIT:**
Since it was not answered after half a day, I asked in the Microsoft support forum too (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie_other-windows_other/style-autodetected-phone-number-links/8363ffe5-fa22-469a-a24d-7b6e0cef7f23?tm=1480409687855 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

There is written, that you are able to prevent this behavior:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337007(v=vs.85).aspx

Alternatively, you can add a link manually:

```
<a href="tel:XXX-XXX-XXX">XXX-XXX-XXX</a>
```

Now you are able to do the styling manually!

Comment: Quote: Setting <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> However I don't want to use that, since not all users will be able to set a correct telphone number link an the featrue is quite usefull.

Comment: Yes - i do understand - so use the href="tel:" - attribute and everything is fine. Visitors can use the numbers and you are able to style it.

Comment: Yes, but the editors might not set that. Beside there are already 5 similar answers to that question, I want one, that can style the link. This question was specific for an autodetected phone number, which should be styled, not how to use a link with tel and not how to dispble the feature.

Comment: Have a closer look at the documentation link. There is a paragraph about "Controlling phone number detection" - you got no other choice, if you want to style those numbers.

Comment: Adding a `<a href="tel:XXX-XXX-XXX">XXX-XXX-XXX</a>` is a bad idea because on many platforms it will provide an unusable or broken link (or a link to some dumb app), while letting the browser do auto-highlight and being able to style it would be better. Desktop browsers without phone call capabilities would simply ignore it and mobiles would set it as as a tappable number (with the style you want). That would be perfect is if we didn't have Edge on the way. Any solution anyone?